# Using Parsec with a recursive data as the stream

Tags: haskell, interpreter, parsec

I'm writing an interpreter for functional programming language with with *mixfix operators*, just like [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Mixfix).

```
if_then_else_ : Bool -> a -> a -> a
if True then x else _  = x
if False then _ else x = x

_/\_ : Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True /\ True = True
_ /\ _ = False
```

So that means I had to run a parser (I used Alex/Happy), to get an AST, with this specific part (smaller than actual `Expr`):

```
data Expr 
  = Id String
  | Apply [Expr]
  | Forall Type Expr

data Type = TypeBind String Expr
```

And with this `Expr`, I have to run a second parser (which I intend to use Parsec) to do the following kind of processing:

```
λ let example = Apply [Id "if", Id "a", Id "/\\", Id "b", Id "then", Id "c", Id "else", Id "d"]
λ parseMixfix example
Right (Apply [Id "if_then_else_",Apply [Id "_/\\_",Id "a",Id "b"],Id "c",Id "d"])
```

I started with a Parser that received a `Stream` of `[Expr]`, but this only accepts the lists in a `Apply`, and doesn't go deep in the *tree*, just parses on the top level.

So I'm considering the option of instead of using `[Expr]` as the `Stream`, to use `Expr`, having to do the `Stream` instance for it; this is where I'm at:

```
data Tok a = This a | Over (Tok a) deriving (Show)

instance (Monad m) => Stream Expr m (Tok Expr) where
        uncons ex = check ex
            where
                check :: Monad m => Expr -> m (Maybe (Tok Expr, Expr))
                check ex = case ex of
                        Id s         -> return $ Just (This (Id s), Apply [])
                        Apply (x:xs) -> do
                                mst <- check x
                                return $ fmap (\(a, b) -> (Over a, b)) mst
```

Which is using `data Tok` as kind of a Zipper breadcrumb (or at least I see it that way), to indicate how deep in the tree it comes from.

I know this is not the correct code, but is for you folks to get the idea. I'm wondering if I'm on the right track or if there's a better solution for this problem. I'm also missing the `Forall` case here; that's because I was making tests with an `Id | Apply` only tree before.

Comment: There is the [Parsing mixfix operators](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.157.7899) paper, which also mentiones a bunch of other relevant papers. It's outdated though, since "the treatment of operators has changed", as Agda often says now.

Comment: That's the paper I've been using to get this going. If it's outdated, where could I find information on how they're treating operators now?

Comment: I'm not aware of any description of what was changed and how. The only thing I know is that Agda now supports sections (e.g. you can write `if_then 1 else_` for `λ b m -> if b then 1 else m`). Try to ask on Agda mailing list.

Comment: Changes (w.r.t. to treating operators in Agda) are described in the [changelog](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/doc/release-notes/2-4-4.txt#L372).